# Trouble with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm trying to practice JS by writing tic-tac-toe. Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var turn = "X";
    $("td").on("click", function() {
        updateTile();
    });
    function updateTile() {
        if ($(this).html() == "") {
            $(this).html("<h1>" + turn + "</h1>");
            updateTurn();
        }
    }
    function updateTurn() {
        if (turn == "X") {
            turn = "O";
        }
        else if (turn == "O") {
            turn = "X";
        }
    }
});
```

It's not working. My debugging has led me to believe that the `$(this)` in `updateTile()` isn't referring to the `$(this)` when `td` is clicked. If so, why is that? `$("td")` is the object that is calling `updateTile()`, so shouldn't `$(this)` refer to the `td` element?

Comment: I don't want to pass in `updateTile()` to `.on` because I have other logic to add to the `.on("click")`.

Comment: Check my answer, i edited it according to your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling an anonymous function instead of your own.

Bind your click like this:

```
$("td").on("click", updateTile);
```

EDIT:

The OP want to do other things on click.

So you can use call to be able to use 'this' and an anonym function.

```
$("td").on("click", function() {
   alert("Click");
   updateTile.call(this);
});
```

Comment: In your answer you are sending the current context to the function, instead of using the context in the function.

Answer (score 2):

You are out of context, so `this` is not the `this` you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var turn = "X";
    $("td").on("click", function() {
        updateTile(this);
    });
    function updateTile(that) {
        if ($(that).html() == "") {
            $(that).html("<h1>" + turn + "</h1>");
            updateTurn();
        }
    }
    function updateTurn() {
        if (turn == "X") {
            turn = "O";
        }
        else if (turn == "O") {
            turn = "X";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by out of context?

Comment: In a function, (anonymous or not) you are in a context (scope) represented by "this" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Answer (score 1):

jQuery internally binds the current element to the `this` context of the function you pass in as the handler. So, just pass in the function directly:

```
$("td").on("click", updateTile);
```